# Window titles/Foreground detection of running applications of all users

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, winapi

Assuming that the application would be executed by `administrator` user on Windows; is there a way to use Windows API to retrieve window titles and detect if application is in foreground from all logged in users?

Trying following code we can't retrieve titles from applications other logged in users are running.

```
// to get the processes
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
// and this to get the title:
process.MainWindowTitle
```

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart we’re implementing a productivity tool. One of the requirements is to show how much time users spend on different applications. Having the title would help us to breakdown the usage to activities.

Comment: Monitoring the foreground application of all users on a computer sounds more like a surveillance tool than a productivity tool to me.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers feel free to guess, but please don't waste bandwidth not answering the question. (thanks for the edit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use getforegroundwindow function from winapi. But it is just one problem. It must be executed in context of user session. It means you must enumerate all user sessions in computer, after take user token, and by using this user token, execute secondary process in user session by CreateProcessAsUser. This secondary process can execute getforegroundwindow, and you must implement any ipc method to return information back to your main application. I used this code in windows service, to execute small programm in context of user session:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        } 

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
                IntPtr hToken,
                string lpApplicationName,
                string lpCommandLine,
                IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
                IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
                bool bInheritHandles,
                UInt32 dwCreationFlags,
                IntPtr lpEnvironment,
                string lpCurrentDirectory,
                ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
                out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public Int32 SessionID;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pWinStationName;

            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }
    public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
    {
        IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
        return server;
    }
    public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
    {
        WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
    }
    public static List<uint> ListSessions(String ServerName)
    {
        IntPtr server = IntPtr.Zero;
        List<uint> ret = new List<uint>();
        server = OpenServer(ServerName);

        try
        {
            IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

            Int32 count = 0;
            Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count);
            Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

            Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo;

            if (retval != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                    current += dataSize;

                    ret.Add((uint)si.SessionID);
                }

                WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServer(server);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        List<uint> retVal =  ListSessions("COMPUTER_NAME");

        for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Count; i++)
        {
            IntPtr userToken = new IntPtr();
            WTSQueryUserToken(retVal[i], out userToken);


            STARTUPINFO info = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

             CreateProcessAsUser(userToken, null, @"c:\windows\notepad.exe",
              IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, (UInt32)0, IntPtr.Zero, null,
            ref info, out procInfo);


        }
```

}

This code is for windows service, and entry point is OnStart() function. In windows, SYSTEM account have all necessary permission to execute this code. I did not check it in Admin context, but probably it will work also.

This code will just execute notepad.exe in all user sessions. You must make you programm, with getforegroundwindow and some sort of interprocess communication

Comment: Polling `GetForegroundWindow` is poor advice. For one, you'll have to answer the question, how often you want to poll. Whichever interval you are suggesting, it's going to miss window activation events, or put undue pressure on a CPU core. [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx), on the other hand, allow you to register callbacks for window creation, destruction, activation, and so on.

Comment: my code don't have any implementation for polling getforegroundwindow. It is just about access window function in context of all users session in computer.

Comment: I didn't imply that you posted the code to do so. You still recommended to use `GetForegroundWindow` which leads to an algorithm that naturally **must** poll. This is poor advice as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, polling is not so good. But for using WinEvents, programmer must make good architecture. Application must be resident in user context, you must keep list of all user session, list of your application id in user context, check, is it still alive in user context, start/restart application in case of user killed task in task manager or freeze, monitor for logon/logout of user session and inject application in new user session. Yes, like difference between small hobby application and production application :))