# How to get the foreground Window of all users?

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows server, 4 users are remotely logged in.

```
GetForegroundWindow returns only current user foreground window.
```

Is there anyway to get foreground window of all users ?

Comment: what's wrong with my question ? May i know why you downvoted ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of how the system separates user sessions.

Comment: You cannot write a system service using PowerShell (which you need). And even if you solved that, asking for the foreground window is in the overwhelming majority of cases the precursor to a completely wrong solution to a problem. Anyway, this is a poor question that's not helpful to anyone.

Comment: This question sounds very much like [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem. Please edit the question and add more details.

Comment: @IInspectable, Okay. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263828/window-titles-foreground-detection-of-running-applications-of-all-users/43285007#43285007

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) I can find for that function (as the name implies) means that it's not an actual cmdlet or something similar. It's actually C++ code so what you're doing is invoking some very complex code and JIT compiling it. By detailing what you're trying to do you might get some better approaches.

With your current approach you won't get far. That call you're using is bound by the user session and as such doesn't know about any of the other users. If you wanted to use this call you would need to execute it in the context of each user. As for actually getting that information natively ... I'm not sure how.